# The associated graded of a filtered coalgebra

Tags: coalgebras, filtrations, graded-algebras

Given a coalgebra $C$ with a filtration $F$ such that $\Delta(F^n C)\subset \sum_{i=0}^n F^i C\otimes F^{n-i} C$, how does the coproduct manifest in the associated graded? Do we get something to the effect of $\Delta(F^n C)\subset F^0 C\otimes F^{n} C + F^n C\otimes F^{0} C$?